# Is there a security flaw in this system design?

Tags: authentication, jwt

I'm working on the authentication part of my application.
Previously, I was using `Firebase` but I decided to work differently for some reason.
As I never implemented such a system, I'm asking for your expertise.

1. The user click on `"Login with Facebook"`
2. The request hits the `Facebook Auth Server` and the user is prompted to log in and authorize the app to access its public profile
3. The Frontend sends the `Facebook User Access Token` to the Gateway that performs the following steps:

   - it sends a request to Facebook to **validate** the `User Access Token`
   - it gets the `email` of the Facebook user by making an API Call to the `Facebook graph API`.
   - it creates a `user ID` that is its `email address` encrypted in some way (TBD) and creates an `App JWT` with these 4 standard claims: `iss`, `sub`, `aud`, `exp`. `sub` will contain the `user ID`.
   - it creates a response containing the `user ID` in the body, and a `Set-Cookie` header that is `secure`, `http only`, `same-site` and `Max-Age` is set to 30 min (A session on the website is up to 10 min max)

- Then, the `Frontend` asks for the user profile to the Gateway providing its `user ID`
- The `Gateway` validates the `App JWT` from the cookie and forward the request to the `User API`
- The `user API` either returns the user profile or creates the user if it didn't find the `user ID`

It looks like this:

[image: flow]

If you want to play with the diagram:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FdxpyMQGXSDTTDiu-I9YuwaPpUCJaSmj/view?usp=sharing

Few other info:

- The Frontend is a `SPA`
- Communication between Front and Gateway is `HTTPS`
- The Gateway and the services are docker services orchestrated by `Docker Swarm`.
- Communication between Gateway and Services is `HTTP` (no auth yet)
- The gateway doesn't provide rate limiting, nor IP restriction (not sure if it's possible though)

Comment: Why are you sending the **User Access Token** to fb to verify it? It's JWT right, just use their public to verify it yourself. Your rest of the approach approach is almost similar to OIDC. Why you don't want to use OIDC for this? It's standardized and certified.

Comment: Hi @defalt! Thanks for the feedback :)
I receive an `access token` from Facebook but it's not an `ID Token` or `JWT` so I can't validate it on my own. (For Google it's different cause I receive an `ID Token`).  Well, I don't really know `OIDC`. What would you suggest to conform to one of their flow? ( I've just found [a list of the `OIDC` diagrams grants](https://darutk.medium.com/diagrams-of-all-the-openid-connect-flows-6968e3990660) I've gonna walk through this).

Comment: OIDC PKCE is the most common protocol for your approach. It uses JWT and it has dedicated endpoint just to retrieve the user information using the access token. It will make your authentication flow less noisy than it is right now. JWT is the way to go because signature verification can be done in memory which is good for your APIs.

Comment: I understand that [the PKCE flow](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce#how-it-works) would be the way to go for a login/pass login to the App, but here the user first logs in to a social network (FB here), and I can see in Google docs ([step 4](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/integrate#sign_in_with_google_in_the_abstract)) that we can use this IDToken to authenticate the user on the App. The front sends the token to the back which validates it.

Comment: So, what problem are you facing with OIDC PKCE?

Comment: Well, I feel like it would add another layer of unnecessary complexity cause the social network already provides an `access_token` (Facebook) or an `ID Token` (Google). And I have to confess that I'm not sure about the procedure...Do you suggest that the Front sends a `code verifier` and a `code challenge` to the gateway along with the token received by the social auth server? Cause steps 4 (redirect to login prompt) and 5 (authenticate and consent) can't apply then ... so I definitely missed something. (Just added the link to the diagram in case you want to show something on it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147066/discussion-between-defalt-and-big-boulard).